# Insert on mongodb using asyncio_mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a situation, I need to add data on mongodb in async mode, so I used [asyncio-mongodb](https://bitbucket.org/mrdon/asyncio-mongo/src) package for adding data.

Everything is OK if I not fill username/password, but when I fill username/password, this error appears:

```
asyncio_mongo._pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: {'code': 16544, 'ok': 1.0, 'n': 0, 'err': 'not authorized for insert on ty_mongodb_memory1.bi_mongo_driver_pos', 'connectionId': 256286}
```

I added data in this collection in sync mode(username/password is correct).

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you create your connection to mongo DB, you have to fill out "DB" parameter

```
asyncio_mongo.Connection.create('hostname', 'port', 
                                username="user", 
                                password="password", 
                                db='PUT YOUR DB NAME HERE')
```